# Split String when character changes. Possible Regex solution?

Tags: java, regex, string, character

I have some `String`s consisting of only digits, and I want to split it whenever the character changes.

For example:

- `"11101100112021120"` goes to: `{"111", "11", "11", "2", "2", "11", "2"}`
- `"222222222"` goes to `{"222222222"}`
- `"222222122"` goes to `{"222222", "1", "22"}`
- `"000000000"` goes to `{}`
- `"0000100000"` goes to `{"1"}`
- `"11121222212112133321"` goes to `{"111", "2", "1", "2222", "1", "2", "11", "2", "1", "333", "2", "1"}`

I want a nice way to do this.

I know two ways to go about this: just brute forcing, or adding section by section. Or, I could go through and remove all 0's and replace with a 0, then add 0's when characters change, and then just do a split on 0's, but both of those ways just look dumb. If anyone has any idea on a better/prettier way to do this, regex or logic, it'd be nice.

Comment: Btw, Google links are appreciated.  I couldn't find any search terms that worked.  Also, I'm saving these in an ArrayList or any other easy way access them.

Comment: You should change your requirements to _I have some Strings consisting of only digits, and I want to split it whenever the character changes_  **and on the digit 0**, to match your examples.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This seems to work like you expect

```
data.split("0+|(?<=([1-9]))(?=[1-9])(?!\\1)");
```

Test:

```
String[] tests = { "11101100112021120", "222222222", "222222122",
        "000000000", "0000100000", "11121222212112133321" };

for (String data : tests) {
    System.out.println(data + " ->" + Arrays.toString(data.split("0+|(?<=([1-9]))(?=[1-9])(?!\\1)")));
    System.out.println("-----------------------");
}
```

output:

```
11101100112021120 ->[111, 11, 11, 2, 2, 11, 2]
-----------------------
222222222 ->[222222222]
-----------------------
222222122 ->[222222, 1, 22]
-----------------------
000000000 ->[]
-----------------------
0000100000 ->[, 1]     // <-- only problem - empty first element 
-----------------------
11121222212112133321 ->[111, 2, 1, 2222, 1, 2, 11, 2, 1, 333, 2, 1]
-----------------------
```

Unfortunately leading zeros will let array to contain additional empty String. To get rid of it you can earlier remove these zeros with `data.replaceFirst("^0+(?=[^0])", "")`

Comment: Note that for a string of all zeroes, doing `replaceFirst("^0+", "")` will cause the split to produce an array with one empty string.  Try `replaceFirst("^0+(?=[^0])", "")` instead to only do the replace when the string starts with zeroes, but isn't *all* zeroes.

Comment: @matts Nice catch. It's hard to see if result of Arrays.toString() -> `[]` is empty array, or array with one empty String :)

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
 str.split( "0+|(?<=(\\d))(?!\\1)" )
```

For strings containing zeros, you will then have to iterate through the array and remove any empty elements.

Comment: This works as said, you will have null/empty elements, which is fine, however Pshemo's does not produce empty elements, but thank you so much!