# Split string into repeated characters

Tags: java, regex, string, split

I want to split the string "aaaabbbccccaaddddcfggghhhh" into "aaaa", "bbb", "cccc". "aa", "dddd", "c", "f" and so on.

I tried this:

```
String[] arr = "aaaabbbccccaaddddcfggghhhh".split("(.)(?!\\1)");
```

But this eats away one character, so with the above regular expression I get "aaa" while I want it to be "aaaa" as the first string.

How do I achieve this?

Comment: @Adri1du40: I am open to other options but don't want to use loop.

Comment: Check this question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15101577/split-string-when-character-changes-possible-regex-solution

Comment: I'm not a Java guy, but wouldn't `string.split()` be slower than a loop?

Comment: @AmalMurali would be less readable too. I don't know about you but reading this regex `(?<=(.))(?!\\1)` is going to make me scratch my head.

Comment: This is trivially done in Haskell: `group "aaaabbbccccaaddddcfggghhhh"` returns the expected result `["aaaa","bbb","cccc","aa","dddd","c","f","ggg","hhhh"]`...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Split regex to extract Strings of contiguous characters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13596454/split-regex-to-extract-strings-of-contiguous-characters)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Try this:

```
String   str = "aaaabbbccccaaddddcfggghhhh";
String[] out = str.split("(?<=(.))(?!\\1)");

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(out));
=> [aaaa, bbb, cccc, aa, dddd, c, f, ggg, hhhh]
```

Explanation: we want to split the string at groups of same chars, so we need to find out the "boundary" between each group. I'm using Java's syntax for positive look-behind to pick the previous char and then a negative look-ahead with a back reference to verify that the next char is not the same as the previous one. No characters were actually consumed, because only two look-around assertions were used (that is, the regular expresion is zero-width).

Comment: Your solution works perfectly. Can you please explain this regex. How it works.

Answer (score 5):

What about capturing in a lookbehind?

```
(?<=(.))(?!\1|$)
```

as a Java string:

```
(?<=(.))(?!\\1|$)
```

Comment: @T.J.Crowder [seems ok here](http://ideone.com/ghhXhg). Why do you think its not working?

Comment: @Reimeus: Because I copied and pasted it without doing the escape. I **really** wish Java had regex literals. :-)

Answer (score 1):

**here I am taking each character and Checking two conditions in the if loop i.e String can't exceed the length and if next character is not equaled to the first character continue the for loop else take new line and print it.**

```
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    char chr= arr[i];
    System.out.print(chr);
    if (i + 1 < arr.length && arr[i + 1] != chr) {
        System.out.print(" \n");
    }
}
```

Comment: For a quality answer, @Shiva can you add some explanation to your answer on how the code accomplish what the author is trying to achieve?

Comment: I was improved the answer@pczeus