# Java Regex to Find Location of Differing Consecutive Characters

Tags: java, regex, split

I have some `String` objects that I need to split into an array of substrings at the locations of differing consecutive characters.

My Input/Output should look like this:

```
"AAAA"    -> ["AAAA"]
"AAAABBB" -> ["AAAA", "BBB"]
"ABBCCC"  -> ["A", "BB", "CCC"]
```

I want to be able to write a line of code like this:

```
String[] charRuns = str.split(regex);
```

Where `str` is the input and `charRuns` is the output, but what should the value of `regex` be?

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15101577/split-string-when-character-changes-possible-regex-solution) might be of use

Comment: I wouldn't regex that...

Comment: @Thomas I will accept any solution that provides the input and output I need, I would just prefer a regex for simple code.

Comment: @oli not as much as [the duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13596454/split-regex-to-extract-strings-of-contiguous-characters)

Answer (score 4):

Can't find a way to do this with `split` yet, but here's a solution based on `Pattern`, `Matcher` and iteration:

```
String test = "ABBCCCDDDDE";
//                          | any character, grouped for back-reference
//                          | | immediate back-reference
//                          | |    | 0+ repetition, greedy
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(.)\\1*");
Matcher m = p.matcher(test);
while (m.find()) System.out.println(m.group());
```

**Output**

```
A
BB
CCC
DDDD
E
```

Comment: This is an awesome solution! I will accept it once I'm sure that a regex doesn't exist for the `str.split` method.

Comment: @4castle thanks! This solution **is** regex-based. But there's probably a way to pass the pattern to `String#split`, although you'd probably need to figure out a way with "look-around"s, as the `split` argument represents the separator, not the token.

Comment: @4castle this is a long-winded way of doing it. See the duplicate for [how to do it using `split()`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13596720/256196)

Comment: @Bohemian Yes,its an exact duplicate. I'm closing this question then.

Answer (score 0):

There is really a simple way to do this without using Java regex at all, here is the pseudocode for it:

get the first character of the string, store it in variable firstChar.

```
count -> 1
startIndex -> 0
create a new arrayList to store the strings.
while(count <= string.length){
   newChar -> string.charAt(count)
   If(newChar != firstChar){
       arrayList.add(string.substring(startIndex, count)
       firstChar = newChar
       startIndex = count
     }
     increment count
  }
```

Once you have the data in arrayList you can iterate over it and create individual arrays.